# how to use customized loss function with mxnet?

Tags: mxnet

I try to learn how to use customized loss function with mxnet.

Bellow is a minimal (not) working example of linear regression. 
When I set 'use_custom = False' everything work fine, rather than custom loss wan't work. What I'm doing wrong?

```
import mxnet as mx
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')

use_custom = False

mx.random.seed(1)

A =  mx.nd.random.uniform(-1, 1, (5, 1))
B =  mx.nd.random.uniform(-1, 1)

X = mx.nd.random.uniform(-1, 1, (100, 5))
y = mx.nd.dot(X, A) + B

iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(data=X, label=y, data_name='data', label_name='label', batch_size=20, shuffle=True)

data  = mx.sym.Variable('data')
label = mx.sym.Variable('label')

net = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data, num_hidden=1)
if use_custom:
    net = mx.sym.MakeLoss(mx.sym.square(net - label))
else:
    net = mx.sym.LinearRegressionOutput(net, label=label)

mod = mx.mod.Module(net, label_names=('label',))
mod.fit(iter, num_epoch=50, eval_metric='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions answered here:
https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/cannot-implement-customized-loss-function/797

Your custom loss is working as expected, you think it is not converging because the `eval_metric` is using the output of your network (the loss) and compare it with the label. In your case I would use a custom evaluation metric, the identity function.

```
mod = mx.mod.Module(net, label_names=['label'])
identity = mx.metric.CustomMetric(lambda x,y:y, name='mse_id')
mod.fit(iter, num_epoch=10, eval_metric=identity, optimizer='adam')
```

This gives you this:

```
INFO:root:Epoch[0] Train-mse_id=0.434285
INFO:root:Epoch[0] Time cost=0.056
INFO:root:Epoch[1] Train-mse_id=0.000387
INFO:root:Epoch[1] Time cost=0.055
INFO:root:Epoch[2] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[2] Time cost=0.055
INFO:root:Epoch[3] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[3] Time cost=0.055
INFO:root:Epoch[4] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[4] Time cost=0.055
INFO:root:Epoch[5] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[5] Time cost=0.056
INFO:root:Epoch[6] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[6] Time cost=0.056
INFO:root:Epoch[7] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[7] Time cost=0.056
INFO:root:Epoch[8] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[8] Time cost=0.056
INFO:root:Epoch[9] Train-mse_id=0.000000
INFO:root:Epoch[9] Time cost=0.056
```