# Output value with Mxnet C++ API

Tags: c++, mxnet, loss-function

I am trying to implement a custom loss function in Mxnet, using its C++ API. The question of loss function has already been risen in python ([how to use customized loss function with mxnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430560/how-to-use-customized-loss-function-with-mxnet)) even though it doesn't address the specific question of the output.

Let say I want to create my own softmax function, I could do the following:

```
         Symbol expFc2 = exp(fc2);
         Symbol sumExp = sum("sumExp", expFc2, dmlc::optional<Shape>(Shape(1)));
         Symbol expandedSumExp = expand_dims("expandedSumExp", sumExp, 1);
         Symbol customSoftmax = broadcast_div(expFc2, expandedSumExp);
         Symbol cross_entropy = (-1) * (one_hot("OneHotDataLabel", data_label, 10) * log(customSoftmax) + (1 - one_hot("OneHotDataLabel", data_label, 10)) * log(1 - customSoftmax));
         Symbol lenet = MakeLoss(cross_entropy);
```

However, whenever I get the output, `auto curOutput = exe->outputs;`, I seem to get the value after the computation of the loss function, which would be the `cross_entropy`.

How to get the result of the `customSoftmax` computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to access intermediate outputs in a computation graph. This is for optimization reasons. Any output you need must be returned as output of the graph. You can use mx.symbol.Group to return multiple symbols as output.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/example/python-howto/multiple_outputs.py) is a Python example. You should be able to do the same thing in C++.